# How to find max fo each datacenter

Tags: sql, function, max, min

I have stable with 6 columns

```
region  datacenter  suite  date1  date2
```

Each region has multiple entry for date 1 and date two, but I want to get a max for each region.

How can I write the syntax? I am currently using:

```
select region, datacenter, suite, max(date1)
```

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: MY code is a simple select statement,

Comment: select region, datacenter, suite, max(date1)

Comment: Tag your database and show us some sample data and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this

```
select region
,datacenter
,suite
,max(date1) over(partition by region) as max_date1
,max(date2) over(partition by region) as max_date2
from your_table;
```

Comment: date 1 and date 2 are different dates, I want to get a max of each date1. for example I want my out come to be   region/datacenter/suite/max(date1)/max(date2)

Comment: @RaminRafat  You're not providing sample output so it's impossible to tell what exactly you're looking for

Comment: @RaminRafat Try the updated solution

Comment: this is working

Comment: @RaminRafat If so, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark

Comment: In general I discourage readers from answering questions where so little prior effort has been evidenced. We do not need hundreds of thousands of members discovering that they can get free work here - we are suffering a deluge of poor quality questions already.